# Arm assembly - multiple push/pop order and SP

Tags: arm, stack

I've seen an annotation for pushing/popping multiple registers in the same line, e.g:

```
push    {fp, lr}
```

I couldn't find out who is pushed first - fp or lr?

An additional question - does SP point to the last occupied address in the stack or the first free one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ARM ARM:

> The registers are stored in sequence, the lowest-numbered register to the lowest memory address (start_address), through to the highest-numbered register to the highest memory address (end_address)

On ARM, the stack pointer normally points to the last occupied address on the stack.  For example, when setting up the initial stack pointer, you normally initialize with with the address one past the end of the stack.

`PUSH` is just a synonym for `STMDB` using `sp` as the base register.  The `DB` indicates the 'decrement-before' addressing mode.

Comment: How calm it's one past the end of the stack? wouldn't it point to the last empty address?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'end'.  I mean the highest address.  Stacks normally grow from high to low addresses.  That means a push decrements the stack pointer and then stores a word.  A pop loads a word and then increments the stack pointer.

Comment: To answer the question directly, the `fp=r11` is pushed before the `lr=r14`.  This ordering is used in the epilogue where you may see `pop {fp,pc}` as the `pc=r15` is numbered beside the *link register*.

Comment: @artlessnoise, I guess that depends on what you mean by 'before'.  If they were pushed in numerical order with independent `push` instructions, rather than as a group, they'd be the other way around.

Comment: They are stored in that order no matter if the stack is ascending or descending, afaik.  I am pretty sure that is what the ARM ARM says for LDM/STM memory transfers.  So in time order, it is **before**.  I don't know if you mean *memory order*; that depends.

Comment: Yeah, the order is the same regardless of the stack direction.  `push`/`pop`, however, require a descending stack.

Comment: So if `LR` is `R14` and `PC` is `R15`, `push {LR, R5}` is the same as `push R5` then `push LR`. And then `pop {PC, R5}` would be in the reverse order of insertion so `pop PC` then `pop R5` (except that can't happen if `PC` is changed before it). Problem is `LR` would always be pushed last since it's higher than the regular registers and a `pop PC` wouldn't let the other pops finish. Am I missing something? Seems like stacking in decreasing order would have been more useful otherwise

Comment: It's a single instruction that push/pops the whole set of requested registers. It's not some kind of macro that expands to doing them one at a time.